# Get a legitimate array from ajax & jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I create a simple ajax call, which retrieves data from my database with json, something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "..",
    url: "..",
    data: ..,
    success:function(data){
        var arrayData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

Then I get an array to `arrayData`, but how can I use it out of the 'success function'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[simshaun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740020/get-a-legitimate-array-from-ajax-jquery-call/6740032#6740032) has answered your immediate question but I suspect that you may also have questions around the asynchronous nature of the AJAX call i.e. `arrayData` will be `undefined` until the response is retruned from the server and the success function is called.

Whatever you want to do with `arrayData` after the success function is called will need to be called from within the success function. For example

```
var arrayData;

$.ajax({
    type: "..",
    url: "..",
    data: ..,
    success:function(data){
        arrayData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        doSomethingElse();
    }
});

function doSomethingElse() {
    /* do something else here with arrayData */
    arrayData.doSomething();
}
```

Now at this point, we can actually remove `arrayData` altogether

```
$.ajax({
    type: "..",
    url: "..",
    data: ..,
    success:function(data){
        doSomethingElse(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
    }
});

function doSomethingElse(data) {
    /* do something else here with the returned data */
    data.doSomething();
}
```

In fact, we can go even further. All the anonymous function that is assigned to the success property is really doing is calling `doSomethingElse` so we could get rid of that and just call `doSomethingElse` directly

```
$.ajax({
    type: "..",
    url: "..",
    data: ..,
    success: doSomethingElse
});

function doSomethingElse(data) {
    /* do something else here with the returned data */
    var arrayData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

}
```

Is this cleaner/clearer?

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare the arrayData var before the ajax call.

```
var arrayData;

$.ajax({
    type: "..",
    url: "..",
    data: ..,
    success:function(data){
        arrayData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

I recommend you read some on variable scope in javascript.

- [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Variable_Scope
- http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+variable+scope

Answer (score 2):

```
var arrayData;
$.ajax({
    type: "..",
    url: "..",
    data: ..,
    success:function(data){
        arrayData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other two answers indicate you have to declare the array outside the success function.  The reason for this is because the function(){ creates an inner scope.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
$.getJSON("sections/view_numbers_update.php?JsonUpdatedFrom=" + intLastUpdate, function(data) {
 $.each(data, function(index, objNumber) {
  $('#tr_' + objNumber.intID).find("td").eq(3).html(objNumber.datLastCalled);
  $('#tr_' + objNumber.intID).find("td").eq(4).html(objNumber.strStatus);
  $('#tr_' + objNumber.intID).find("td").eq(5).html(objNumber.intDuration);
  $('#tr_' + objNumber.intID).find("td").eq(6).html(objNumber.blnWasHuman);
 });
});
```

(For a table with `<tr id="tr_<?php echo $arrRecord["intID"] ?>">` etc.)